# How to do popup authentication in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have asp.net mvc project (4.5 framework). We need authentication popup with forms mode. In **web.config** we have

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/SignIn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Questing is How we can show popup for authentication when it needs. When user click to Authorized method of controller, we need show popup, then execute AccountController.Authenticate method, if all good redirect to returnUrl.

I have **AccountController** with 3 methods

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult SignIn(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    ViewBag.NeedAuth = true;
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", returnUrl);            
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Authenticate(AuthenticateObject auth, string returnUrl)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(auth.Phone, true);
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}

public void SignOut()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();        
}
```

Then _layout.cshtml contain partial to popup view

```
    @model Rentago.Web.Site.ViewObjects.BaseViewObject

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta name="theme-color" content="#50E3C2">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,300,700&amp;subset=latin,cyrillic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <title>Index</title>
     @Styles.Render("~/Content/ion")
     @Styles.Render("~/Content/swiper")
     @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <header class="header">
        // header
     </header>
     @RenderBody();
     // footer
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/basejs")    
     @RenderSection("scripts", false)
     @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false && ViewBag.NeedAuth != null && ViewBag.NeedAuth) { 
       @Html.Partial("_LogInPartial", Model.Auth)
     }
```

Then **_LoginPartial.cshtml** contains popup form.

```
 @model Rentago.Web.Site.ViewObjects.AuthenticateObject

 <div id="modalContainer" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-overlay"></div>
   <div class="modal">
    <a data-ui="modal-close" class="modal-close"><img src="/images/close.svg"></a>
     <div class="modal-guts">
       @using (Html.BeginForm("Authenticate", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "auth" })) {
        <div class="modal__row">
            <div class="modal__content text--center">
                <label class="modal__label">Введите номер мобильного, чтобы войти</label>
                @*<input type="text" placeholder="+7 [000] 000-00-00" class="ui-input ui-input--big ui-input--wide">*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Phone, new { placeholder = "+7 [000] 000-00-00", @class = "ui-input ui-input--big ui-input--wide" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Phone)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal__row">
            <ul class="modal__list">
                <li>
                    Только для регистрации/входа
                </li>
                <li>
                    Нет спама
                </li>
                <li>
                    Новичкам дарим <span>3 контакта собственника бесплатно</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="modal__agreement">
                Выполняя вход, вы принимаете условия <a>пользовательского соглашения</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal__row text--center">
            <input data-ui="modal-login" class="button button--big" type="submit">
       </div>
       }
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: What is the issue exactly? Is the pop-up not showing? Is the authentication not working on POST? You seem to have a solution prototype, but what is the behavior you're having today we can help you with?

Comment: problem is popup show always, we need show only when it need. when user go to Authorized method and he not loged